# Indesign script that applies 'Multiply' transparency effect to PDF placed on a layer to multiple pages

Tags: indesign-scripting

I have a 220pp Indesign document with a Cyan,Magenta and Yellow PDF placed on each page.
I have another layer with a Black PDF on each page. I need to apply a Transparency Effect of 'Multiply' to all the black PDF's. Can this be done with a script?

Comment: It is possible. Though it applies to an older version (CS6) [this may be a starting point](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-assign-blend-mode-to-a-graphic-in-indesign-cs6-javascript/td-p/9161504)